# How do you create a compressed dataset in pytables that can store a Unicode string?

Tags: python, string, unicode, compression, pytables

I'm using PyTables to store a data array, which works fine; along with it I need to store a moderately large (50K-100K) Unicode string containing JSON data, and I'd like to compress it.

How can I do this in PyTables? It's been a long time since I've worked with HDF5, and I can't remember the right way to store character arrays so they can be compressed. (And I can't seem to find a similar example of doing this on the PyTables website.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PyTables does not natively support unicode - yet.  To store unicode. First convert the string to bytes and then store a VLArray of length-1 strings or uint8.  To get compression simply instantiate your array with a `Filters` instance that has a non-zero `complevel`.

All of the examples I know of storing JSON data like this do so using the HDF5 C-API.

Comment: Just curious, why a VLArray rather than a CArray or EArray? I'm still learning the API, so it's unfamiliar territory to me.

Comment: The VL refers to the length of the element being 'variable length'.  In Arrays, CArrays, EArrays, and Tables all elements or rows must be the exact same length / size.  Since you can't ensure that all data will be the same size in bytes (because of how unicode works) and selecting the longest string as the length for all members is wasteful, it is best to use a variable length data structure.

Answer (score 3):

OK, based on Anthony Scopatz's approach, I have a feasible solution.

```
def recordStringInHDF5(h5file, group, nodename, s, complevel=5, complib='zlib'):
    '''creates a CArray object in an HDF5 file 
    that represents a unicode string'''

    bytes = np.fromstring(s.encode('utf-8'),np.uint8)
    atom = pt.UInt8Atom()
    filters = pt.Filters(complevel=complevel, complib=complib)
    ca = h5file.create_carray(group, nodename, atom, shape=(len(bytes),),
                               filters=filters)
    ca[:] = bytes
    return ca
def retrieveStringFromHDF5(node):
    return unicode(node.read().tostring(), 'utf-8')
```

If I run this:

```
>>> h5file = pt.openFile("test1.h5",'w')
>>> recordStringInHDF5(h5file, h5file.root, 'mrtamb',
    u'\u266b Hey Mr. Tambourine Man \u266b')

/mrtamb (CArray(30,), shuffle, zlib(5)) ''
  atom := UInt8Atom(shape=(), dflt=0)
  maindim := 0
  flavor := 'numpy'
  byteorder := 'irrelevant'
  chunkshape := (65536,)

>>> h5file.flush()
>>> h5file.close()
>>> h5file = pt.openFile("test1.h5")
>>> print retrieveStringFromHDF5(h5file.root.mrtamb)

♫ Hey Mr. Tambourine Man ♫
```

I've been able to run this with strings in the 300kB range and gotten good compression ratios.

Comment: `The binary mode of fromstring is deprecated, as it behaves surprisingly on unicode inputs. Use frombuffer instead`